# Why IDisposable is an Interface, not abstract class?

Tags: c#

Can we define IDisposable as an abstract class instead of Interface like below. What are disadvantages?

```
public abstract class absDisposable
{
    public abstract void Dispose();
}

public class childClass : absDisposable
{
    SqlConnection objConnect = new SqlConnection("connstring");

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.objConnect != null)
        {
            this.objConnect.Dispose();
            this.objConnect = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote that code in the same Interface works, else there is no reason of abstract class with no implementation. This is same way we define Interface, without any implementations.right? However, the question is not the IDisposable only, its about all Interfaces we use. Why don't we simply write the methods we require, why do we go one level more for Implementing Interfaces? Since Interface serves no purpose. We always have to give our own implementations in derived classes, so no question of code re-usability also. And how Interfaces resolve lack of multiple inheritance in c#, if we cannot re-use codes? All I want to know is what situation an Interface proves its presence?

Comment: what? that makes no sense. What if you need to derive from something else?

Comment: Why would you ever want this?

Comment: Does that mean, if I do not need to derive from anything else, then IDisposable could be an abstract class? or, Is there any other advantage of not making it as abstract class?

Comment: @Bazzz: I am just trying to understand the right use of Interface. When I can define something as Interface not abstract class?

Comment: @SAM an abstract class defines some implementation that you want all derived classes to have. An interface does *not* provide an implementation, it only defines structure. Since `IDisposable` does not have any implementation, it adds no value if you define it as an abstract class, actually you'll lose value in terms of inheritance because a derived class can inherit only 1 other class. See SLaks' answer. Simply explained, interfaces are to assign a class to a certain "group". Does my class belong to the group of classes that can be disposed? Yes! IDisposable... etc.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aredundant

Comment: You should ask one question per question. *Why don't we simply write the methods we require, why do we go one level more for Implementing Interfaces? Since Interface serves no purpose. We always have to give our own implementations in derived classes, so no question of code re-usability also. And how Interfaces resolve lack of multiple inheritance in c#, if we cannot re-use codes? All I want to know is what situation an Interface proves its presence?*

Comment: The point of an interface is to introduce a new **type**.

Answer (score 9):

Since C# does not support multiple inheritance, your idea would make it impossible to combine disposability with an existing base class.

Since `IDisposable` doesn't include any implementation, there is no reason to make it an abstract class.

Comment: Agree. When we implement IDisposable interface, we give implementation to Dispose() also. Then why to remember the extra IDisposable interface name, then give implementation. Why don't we just write our Dispose() method straight away in derive class since we need that? For instance say my derive class does not need multiple inheritance? I apologize if that is an invalid argument.

Comment: @SAM Because simply calling a method `Dispose` does not mean it's meant to be invoked for deterministic resource disposal. You could also do silly things like `private void Dispose() { ... }`.

Comment: Plus, Given an arbitrary object, one would have to use reflection to determine if it was disposable or not.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yes we can write silly codes like above and make things work, but we loose the Multiple Implementation feature. Is that the only reason we choose Interfaces over abstract classes?

Comment: @SAM - Let's look at it from the other side: what would be the benefit of having an abstract disposable class which has no implementation itself? You ask if not losing the possibility to inherit from some other base class is the *only* reason. Well, that's a pretty big reason in and of itself. With an abstract class, you have this disadvantage without having any advantage. So what would be he point?

Comment: @SAM - The answer is still the same, you can implement a lot of different interfaces, but with abstract classes, you are limited to one. What if you want a class to be disposable and compareable? You can't inherit from two abstract classes. Would you make a third one? Or one for every posible combination? Seems very wrong. Yes, with interfaces, you have to implement everything each time & risk having duplicate code. But there are other techniques to avoid that. And most of the time that is the *strength* of using interfaces. Vastly *different* implementations that still give the "same" result.